# How can I edit/remove the " u= " marker in git-sh

Tags: git, git-config, git-shell

Using [rtomayko's git-sh](https://github.com/rtomayko/git-sh), I've noticed a marker that I haven't seen in the examples.
[image: prompt]

**u=** (which I imagine stands for *upstream*) tells me how many commits I've committed locally, but have not pushed to the remote repo. I'd like to update it's styling, but I can't seem to figure out it's exact name so I can change it in my .gitconfig!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the code](https://github.com/rtomayko/git-sh/blob/master/git-sh.bash) it looks like the `u=` is added by `_git_upstream_state`, which is called via the following definition:

```
PS1='`_git_headname``_git_upstream_state`!`_git_repo_state``_git_workdir``_git_dirty``_git_dirty_stash`> '
```

Comment: I feel like today is the day I stop looking at the docs and start looking at source code. 

Thanks!!